# How to convert pandas dataframe so that index is the unique set of values and data is the count of each value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` from a multiple choice questions and it is formatted like so:

```
      Sex Qu1  Qu2  Qu3
Name
Bob    M   1    2    1
John   M   3    3    5
Alex   M   4    1    2
Jen    F   3    2    4
Mary   F   4    3    4
```

The data is a rating from 1 to 5 for the 3 multiple choice questions.  I want rearrange the data so that the index is range(1,6) where 1='bad', 2='poor', 3='ok', 4='good', 5='excellent', the columns are the same and the data is the count of the number occurrences of the values (excluding the Sex column).  This is basically a histogram of fixed bin sizes and the x-axis labeled with strings.  I like the output of `df.plot()` much better than  `df.hist()` for this but I can't figure out how to rearrange the table to give me a histogram of data.  Also, how do you change x-labels to be strings?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Series.value_counts` gives you the histogram you're looking for:

```
In [9]: df['Qu1'].value_counts()
Out[9]: 
4    2
3    2
1    1
```

So, apply this function to each of those 3 columns:

```
In [13]: table = df[['Qu1', 'Qu2', 'Qu3']].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts())

In [14]: table
Out[14]: 
   Qu1  Qu2  Qu3
1    1    1    1
2  NaN    2    1
3    2    2  NaN
4    2  NaN    2
5  NaN  NaN    1

In [15]: table = table.fillna(0)

In [16]: table
Out[16]: 
   Qu1  Qu2  Qu3
1    1    1    1
2    0    2    1
3    2    2    0
4    2    0    2
5    0    0    1
```

Using `table.reindex` or `table.ix[some_array]` you can rearrange the data.

To transform to strings, use table.rename:

```
In [17]: table.rename(index=str)
Out[17]: 
   Qu1  Qu2  Qu3
1    1    1    1
2    0    2    1
3    2    2    0
4    2    0    2
5    0    0    1

In [18]: table.rename(index=str).index[0]
Out[18]: '1'
```

Comment: This is just what I needed.  Thanks.  The one issue I found is when I normalized the data to percentage (per column) and used names for some of the indexes then plotted it the x-axis labels were incorrectly squished to the left.  If I leave the index as integers or data values as integers it works correctly.